# Issue with AngularJS application while changing DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Webapp which changes a button after each click. Each click will change the button by accessing the content from a different server. However it stops after first click. I seek your advice and help in this regard. The codes are as follows.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="divcont" ng-controller="OpenLink">
    <button ng-click="openLink('text1')">Change Link</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript: app.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myapp.controller('OpenLink', ['$scope', '$http', OpenLink]);

function OpenLink($scope, $http) {
  $scope.openLink = function(s) {
    var elink = "http://10.0.0.1:8080/" + s + ".txt";
    alert("ELINK is " + elink);
    $http.get(elink)
      .then(function(response) {
        document.getElementById("divcont").innerHTML = response.data;
      }, function(response) {
        alert("Error");
      });
  }
}
```

The remote files and their contents are as follows

1. text1.txt contains "`<button ng-click="openLink('text2')">Text 1 </button>`"
2. text2.txt contains "`<button ng-click="openLink('text3')">Text 2</button>`"
3. text3.txt contains "`<button ng-click="openLink('text1')">Text 3</button>`"

How can I make it work?

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? If not, your error handler function should be imporved by outputting the error itself also. Right now it will hide it.
Second of all you should NEVER do direct DOM manipulation (``document.getElementById("divcont").innerHTML = response.data;``) from Angular controllers.  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: @rajkumar58, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes!!!... Both the solutions worked..

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert the returned html into DOM, you need to tell Angular to process this piece of html, find directives (`ng-click`) and setup watchers and bindings. This process is called compilation and linking and is performed using `$compile` service. Here is how this service can be used in your example:

```
function OpenLink($scope, $http, $compile) {
  $scope.openLink = function(s) {
    var elink = "http://10.0.0.1:8080/" + s + ".txt";
    alert("ELINK is " + elink);
    $http.get(elink)
      .then(function(response) {
        // you need to compile html first
        var compiledHTML = $compile(response.data)($scope)[0];
        document.getElementById("divcont").appendChild(compiledHTML);
      }, function(response) {
        alert("Error");
      });
  }
}
```

As @tiblu mentioned, it's not good idea to manipulate DOM inside the controller. It's better to use custom directive for that matter. But even inside the custom directive, you'll still have to compile the content returned from server before appending it to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular HTML files instead of TXT files and using *ng-include* directive. It should then be more angular approach. 
HTML:

```
<div id="divcont" ng-controller="OpenLink" ng-include="includedFile"></div>
```

JS

```
app.controller('OpenLink', ['$scope', OpenLink]);

  function OpenLink($scope){
    $scope.includedFile = 'init.html';
    $scope.openLink = function (s) {
      var elink = s + ".html";
      $scope.includedFile = elink;
      console.log("ELINK is " + elink);
    }
  }
```

I added initial HTML as *init.html* file for convenience

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OzZexJmFlxU3GyxscuoY?p=preview